# How to use mvcContrib template gallery for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

Has any one ever downloaded and made use of the mvcContrib template gallery for asp.net mvc. I cant find where to download the templates from and there is no documentation for how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the templates from the source tab on codeplex from [here](http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).

Each template has a folder and each folder has a zip file containing the masterpage the css and and images needed.